# If a struct is a value type why can I new it?

Tags: c#, struct, new-operator, value-type

In C# structs are value types, but I am able to `new` them as if they are reference types.  Why is this?

Comment: A constructor is really just a method that gets the special privilege of messing with an object before it is considered initialized.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Because they have constructors.

The [`new` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx) doesn't mean "this is a reference type"; it means "this type has a constructor". When you `new` something you create an instance, and in doing so you invoke a constructor.

For that matter, *all* value and reference types have constructors (at the very least a default constructor taking no args if the type itself doesn't define any).

Comment: Thanks. For Java, is "all value and reference types have constructors" also true?

Comment: @Ben: I understand that Java primitive types do also have constructors.

Comment: Thanks. But why in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47024170   `new` can't apply to `int`.

Comment: @Ben: Because Java doesn't allow it?

Comment: How can you show that `int` in Java has constructor?

Answer (score 18):

`new` operator doesn't mean that it can be used only for *reference types*. It can be used with *value types* also.

From [new Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx)

> *Used to create **objects** and **invoke constructors**.*

Since every *value type* implicitly has a public default constructor, all value types has default values. You can read [Default Values Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx).

For example;

```
int i = new int(); // i will be 0 for because its default values.
```

Default value for struct type;

> The value produced by setting all value-type fields to **their default
>   values** and all reference-type fields to **null**.

Also From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx):

> When you create a struct object using the new operator, **it gets
>   created and the appropriate constructor is called**. Unlike classes,
>   structs can be instantiated without using the new operator. If you do
>   not use new, the fields will remain unassigned and the object cannot
>   be used until all of the fields are initialized.

Comment: +1 as fast, for the msdn link. Maybe remove the `(v=vs.71)` part?

Comment: See that corrected, but unable to +2 ..

Answer (score 3):

It says right [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx) in the MSDN document, the `new` operator is used to invoke the default constructor of a value type.

Answer (score 3):

You can "new" an integer as well.
The difference is you CANT pass a reference class by value.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the new operator to create a struct. If you do it will call its constructor, if you don't all field will remain unassigned.